# What does it mean to compose two Functors?

Tags: haskell, theory, functor

[Exercise 5 of the Haskell Typeclassopedia Section 3.2](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia#Instances) asks for a proof or counterexample on the statement

> *The composition of two Functors is also a Functor.*

I thought at first that this was talking about composing the `fmap` methods defined by two separate instances of a `Functor`, but that doesn't really make sense, since the types wouldn't match up as far as I can tell. For two types `f` and `f'`, the types of `fmap` would be `fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` and `fmap :: (a -> b) -> f' a -> f' b`, and that doesn't really seem composable. So what does it mean to compose two `Functors`?

Comment: Have you tried actually composing fmap with itself in ghci?  i.e. `:t fmap . fmap`

Comment: @MrBones Thanks for the tip! For those who don't have ghci access, the output is `:: (Functor f1, Functor f) => (a -> b) -> f (f1 a) -> f (f1 b)`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A `Functor` gives two mappings: one on the type level mapping types to types (this is the `x` in `instance Functor x where`), and one on the computation level mapping functions to functions (this is the `x` in `fmap = x`). You are thinking about composing the computation-level mapping, but should be thinking about composing the type-level mapping; e.g., given

```
newtype Compose f g x = Compose (f (g x))
```

can you write

```
instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (Compose f g)
```

? If not, why not?

Comment: This is an excellent answer that explains the Typeclassopedia exercise without giving away the solution.

Answer (score 20):

What this is talking about is the composition of **type constructors** like `[]` and `Maybe`, not the composition of functions like `fmap`.  So for example, there are two ways of composing  `[]` and `Maybe`:

```
newtype ListOfMabye a = ListOfMaybe [Maybe a]
newtype MaybeOfList a = MaybeOfList (Maybe [a])
```

The statement that the composition of two `Functors` is a `Functor` means that there is a formulaic way of writing a `Functor` instance for these types:

```
instance Functor ListOfMaybe where
    fmap f (ListOfMaybe x) = ListOfMaybe (fmap (fmap f) x) 

instance Functor MaybeOfList where
    fmap f (MaybeOfList x) = MaybeOfList (fmap (fmap f) x)
```

In fact, the Haskell Platform comes with the module [`Data.Functor.Compose`](http://lambda.haskell.org/platform/doc/current/packages/transformers-0.3.0.0/doc/html/Data-Functor-Compose.html) that gives you a `Compose` type that does this "for free":

```
import Data.Functor.Compose

newtype Compose f g a = Compose { getCompose :: f (g a) }

instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (Compose f g) where
    fmap f (Compose x) = Compose (fmap (fmap f) x)
```

`Compose` is particularly useful with the `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

newtype ListOfMaybe a = ListOfMaybe (Compose [] Maybe a)
   -- Now we can derive Functor and Applicative instances based on those of Compose
   deriving (Functor, Applicative)
```

Note that the composition of two `Applicative`s is also an `Applicative`.  Therefore, since `[]` and `Maybe` are `Applicative`s, so is `Compose [] Maybe` and `ListOfMaybe`.  Composing `Applicative`s is a really neat technique that's slowly becoming more common these days, as an alternative to monad transformers for cases when you don't need the full power of monads.

Comment: Surely the most useable of all answers here. Let me ask you further: when you write fmap f (Compose x) what is the type of x? I'd say it is f g a, but still I struggle to visualize the computation (fmap (fmap f) x). Gotta think harder about getCompose. 

NB: I understand that the letter "f" is used here in two different roles.

Comment: @MarcoFaustinelli You can tell what type it is by looking at the constructor for Compose that you are matching against. Since `newtype Compose f g a = Compose (f (g a))`, it must be the case that when you pattern-match against it you get a value of type `f (g a)`.

Comment: @MarcoFaustinelli if it were defined as `newtype Compose f g a = MkCompose (f (g a))`, that it'd be `fmap foo (MkCompose x) = MkCompose (fmap (fmap foo) x)`.

Answer (score 14):

It really helps to think about the categorical interpretation here, a functor `F: C -> D` takes objects (values) and morphisms (functions) to objects and morphisms from a category `C` to objects and morphisms in a category `D`.

For a second functor `G : D -> E` the composition of functors `G . F : C -> E` is just taking the codomain of `F` `fmap` transformation to be the domain of the `G` `fmap` transformation. In Haskell this is accomplished with a little newtype unwrapping.

```
import Data.Functor

newtype Comp f g a = Comp { unComp :: f (g a) }

compose :: f (g a) -> Comp f g a
compose = Comp

decompose :: Comp f g a -> f (g a)
decompose = unComp

instance (Functor f, Functor g) => Functor (Comp f g) where
  fmap foo = compose . fmap (fmap foo) . decompose
```

Comment: Does `f` refer to `functor` and `function` at the same time?  If the answer were yes, then why does the type constraint of `Functor f` not apply to `f` in `fmap f`?

Answer (score 13):

The composition of two *functions* is when you put one function inside another function, such as

```
round (sqrt 23)
```

This is the composition of the two functions `round` and `sqrt`. Similarly, the composition of two *functors* is when you put one functor inside another functor, such as

```
Just [3, 5, 6, 2]
```

List is a functor, and so is Maybe. You can get some intuition for why their composition also is a functor if you try to figure out what fmap should do to the above value. Of course it should map over the contents of the inner functor!